# if statement with recursive function angular

Tags: angular, typescript, if-statement, recursion

I am a beginner, I am blocked, I have a test which calls for a recursive function, after the execution of this function and according to its return value we do processing, the function return true, after return false even if the condition is valid, it stays in loop true false, true false.how to stop the execution of the function as soon as i have true, I am trying but need help, can anyone point me in the right direction please.

```js
if (ROUTES.length) {
  if(this.Validate(ROUTES)){
     return true;
  } 
  else {
    this.location.back();
  }
}


Validate(list: Route[]) {    
  for (let x of list) {
    if (this.router.url === x.path) {
      return true;
    } else if (x.menu.length !== 0) {
      return this.Validates(x.menu);
    } 

  }

  return false;

}
```

Comment: What is `this.path`? Your Validate function return a boolean that's not being assigned. Maybe that's the error? I think you should change the first if condition to `if(this.Validate(ROUTES)) { ... }`

Comment: i change but is same probleme if (ROUTES.length !== 0) {
  if(this.Validate(ROUTES)){
     return true;
  } 
  else {
    this.location.back();
  }
}

Comment: What is the purpose of this function? I seriously can't understand it. If for example the `else if` doesn't get reached once, you are basically always taking the last iteration as a result value (since the path variable is getting re-assigned every cycle)

Comment: Can you try changing `return this.Validates(x.menu)` with `this.Validates(x.menu); break;`

Comment: the validate function aims to browse a nested JSON object, return true if the URL == path, if there are a children it returns recursively otherwise it is return false, another function which tests the routing of the application calls this function, return true if Validate is valid and exit the loop otherwise go back and return false

Comment: @FranciscoSantorelli 
I changed but the same problem, the first time returns valid, the second time goes to the else condition (this.location.back())

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Do Simple**: Stop for-loop only when receive result true, otherwise continue to check next elements of the loop until the end.

```
 if (ROUTES.length) {
  if(this.Validate(ROUTES)){
     return true;
  } 
  else {
    this.location.back();
  }
}


Validate(list: Route[]) {    
  for (let x of list) {
    if (this.router.url === x.path) {
      return true;
    } else if (x.menu.length !== 0) {

      const result = this.Validates(x.menu);

      //**** return once got true
      if(result){ 
        return true;
      }

    }

  }

  return false;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some improvements you can make:

- number => boolean conversion works that if number is 0 is false, otherwise it's true. So you can just do `if (x.menu.length)` because if length is 0, it will be false (exactly the same as length !== 0).

Also, I would rewrite your recursive function like so:

```
Validate(list: Route[]): string[] {
  function getPaths(route: Route): string[] {
    let pathArr = [];
    if (route.menu) {
      pathArr = getPaths(route.menu);
    };
    pathArr.push(route.path);

    return pathArr;
  }

  const pathList = list.reduce((pList, route) => {
    return [...pList, ...getPaths(route)];
  }, []);

  return pathList.indexOf(this.router.url) > -1;
}
```

in the case you expect to stop execution of function as soon as you hit true, then you can respond to this and I can think of something else.

PS: wrote directly on SO without testing, maybe its buggy or something, please let me know

Comment: ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at getPaths ( function getPaths(route: Route): string[]),    i think Error: Maximum call stack size exceeded means you have an infinite loop somewhere

Comment: yes, probably in the return of the reduce. If you change it for `pList.push(getPaths(route)); return pList;` does it go away?